# Does Android have some kind of OS or device level cache?

Tags: android, caching

I have an Android app that connects to a backend API. I read data by calling something like `/readdata?id=1`

If I call this API I can successfully read the data. If I update it on the backend and call this exactly the same way, I don't see the updated data. I can even uninstall and reinstall the app and still not see the updated data. It takes about 24 hours to update, even though I am able to see the update normally if I use a browser on my computer.

It seems as if there were a cache beyond the app level (maybe a OS or device level) that is caching the request.

Is this a known issue? Maybe something on Samsung devices?

Thanks

Comment: there is no such cache. It is probably something wrong with the way you get the data, or with the server itself

Answer (score 0):

As Vladyslav Matviienko commented, the problem most likely is either:

- The way you are getting the data. If you are using some library to access the API, chances are responses are cached. A good library should provide an option to request a fresh response. See if you have that one there.
- Or, the problem is on the server side, which I'm not very familiar with (could be cached requests/responses), but I doubt that this is the problem.